# Setting dropdownlist values from selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist which contains some values such as "Hot water" and "Electricity" in C# ASP.Net. What I would like to do is if the user selects one of these values and clicks on a button, then it would set the values of a second dropdownlist to certain values. e.g. if "Hot Water" was chosen and next was clicked then the values in dropdownlist2 would be "Radiator" and "Heating controls". But if "Electricity" was chosen then the values in dropdownlist2 would be "No Power" and "Sockets". My code so far:

```
protected void NextButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    option1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = option1;
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Hot Water")
    {
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Heating controls";
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Underfloor Heating";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your sample code?

Comment: Add sample code to the question. Edit it and add, and let the users know what is the problem that you have faced and what ways did you try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you with the following:

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Hot Water"){
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList2.Items.Add("Radiator");
    DropDownList2.Items.Add("Heating Controls");
}
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Electricity"){
    // Do the same like above but for the values in Electricity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the `Hot Water` or `Electricity` is selected in the dropdownlist1 in `Nextclick` button code like this.

```
if(dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == "Hot Water")
{
    drodownlist2.Items.Add(new ListItem("Radiator","Radiator")); //First parameter take datatextfield and second parameter take datavaluefield.
    drodownlist2.Items.Add(new ListItem("Heating Controls","Heating Controls"));
}
else
{
    drodownlist2.Items.Add(new ListItem("No Power","No Power"));
    drodownlist2.Items.Add(new ListItem ("Sockets","Sockets"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can multi-select in a dropdown list so use a `asp:ListControl` or `asp:CheckBoxList` instead.

If you want a dropdown multiselect there are plenty of JS controls that will do that for you.
eg: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Once you update your code for a list than everything should work fine.